# How to hide # in textview with matcher

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, matcher

Example: My application set my `textview` with #.

Here is the code:

```
Spannable hashText = (Spannable)lblDesc2.getText();

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashText);

while (matcher.find())
{
     hashText.setSpan(
         new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), matcher.start()
         , matcher.end(), 0
     );
     hashText2.setSpan(
         new UnderlineSpan(), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0
     );
}
lblDesc2.setText(hashText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot modify a Spannable, you need to use SpannableStringBuilder and call `setSpan` on each match. Then you can call `delete` to remove the # character that you don't want.

Comment: Please dont forget to mark as answered if this helped. Thanks